# QueryDSL wrong parenthesis with 'OR' and 'AND'

Tags: querydsl

`anyOf(org.id.isNull(),
        org.employees.contains(employee))
        .and(org.id.eq(currentOrg.getId()))`

The expected query is:

```
org.id is null or (org_id=? and (? in (select employees2_.employees_id from org_employees employee2_ where abstractor1_.id=employees2_.org_id))))
```

But the result:

```
org.id is null or org_id=? and (? in (select employees2_.employees_id from org_employees employee2_ where abstractor1_.id=employees2_.org_id)))
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

> What am I missing?

Your bracket matching is off, querydsl is doing the right thing.

`anyOf` isn't required here, an `or` and `and` would do it. Something like:

```
org.id.isNull()
.or(org.id.eq(<something>).and(<subquery>))
```